# Function.prototype.bind.apply() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-binding

I've a function `myfunc` and want to `bind` it to a specific `this` argument and other arguments to `bind` as a single array, not parameters list (cause I get the parameters list as an argument of function, where this code is executed).
For that purpose I use `apply` on `bind` as follows:

```
var myfunc = function(arg1, arg2){
    alert("this = " + this + ", arg1 = " + arg1 + ", arg2 = " + arg2);
}
var bindedMyfunc = myfunc.bind.apply("mythis", ["param1", "param2"]);
bindedMufunc();
```

This results in `Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function`.

What am I doing wrong? Could you explain in detail, what's going onwhen I run this code, cause reality seems to contradict my opinion on that?

**Summary of answers:**
Seems that `bind` itself has its own `this` argument, which is the function, it is called on. E.g. when you say `myfunc.bind(args)`, `bind`'s `this` is `myfunc`.

By calling `apply` on `bind` I've mistakingly assigned `bind`'s this  to "mythis", which is not a function and `bind` can't be called on it.

So, the solution is to use

```
myfunc.bind.apply(myfunc, ["mythis"].concat(["param1", "param2"]))
```

Also, if you want to call the binded myfunc right off, you could say:

```
myfunc.apply.bind(myfunc)("mythis", ["param1", "param2"])
```

but this doesn't suffice my case, cause I need to pass the binded function as an argument to `addEventListener`.

Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: The first solution is `myfunc.bind.apply(myfunc, ["mythis", "param1", "param2"]))`, you forgot the array literal in your summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the function as the first parameter to the `apply` method. The use of `myfunc.bind` doesn't associate the function with the call, it has the effect of `Function.prototype.bind`, and you can just as well use that.

The first parameter for the `bind` method (`thisArg`) should be the first item in the array.

```
var bindedMyfunc = Function.prototype.bind.apply(myfunc, ["mythis", "param1", "param2"]);
```

Comment: Ah, I thinks I understand, what was wrong thanks to your example. `bind` has its own `this`, which should be the function it is called on (`myfunc`) in this case. So, I have to give `myfunc` as first argument and then build a list of arguments from `mythis` and  `[param1, param2]` with `concat`.

Answer (score 3):

> Seems that bind itself has its own this argument, which is the function, it is called on. E.g. when you say `myfunc.bind(args)`, `bind`'s `this` is `myfunc`.

Exactly. If you want to apply `bind`, then you have to apply it to the function (the first parameter), and pass the `bind` arguments (including the intended `this` value) as an array (the second paramter):

```
(Function.prototype.bind).apply(myfunc, ["mythis", "param1", "param2"])
// which is equivalent to
myfunc.bind("mythis", "param1", "param2")
(…args) => myfunc.call("mythis", "param1", "param2", …args) // ES6 syntax
```

However, there is another way to solve your problem: bind `apply` to the function, and partially apply the proposed `apply` arguments:

```
(Function.prototype.apply).bind(myfunc, "mythis", ["param1", "param2"])
// which is equivalent to
(…args) => myfunc.apply("mythis", ["param1", "param2"], …args) // ES6 syntax
```

Comment: The problem with the second method is `..args` becomes useless, I was also thinking about something like this `(fn.call).bind.apply(call, [fn, "this", params]).apply.bind()` but following all of the `this` values becomes so convoluted it'd be cleaner to write a wrapper

Comment: Yes, `…args` become useless, but it seemed you didn't want to use them anyway in your `bindedMufunc();` call? If you want `bindedMufunc` to receive further arguments, you have to use the first approach.

Comment: @PaulS. Sorry, guys, for introducing some confusion yesterday with edits of my question - just successfully tested out`myfunc.bind.apply(myfunc, ["mythis"].concat(["param1", "param2"]))` solution. It works ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bob: I think you should accept Guffa's answer then

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to `bind` `apply` rather than `apply`ing `bind`?

```
var bindedMyfunc = Function.prototype.apply.bind(myfunc);
bindedMyfunc('obj', [1, 2]); // this = obj, arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2
```

I often use this pattern to make `hasOwnProperty` checks shorter without being shadowable;

```
var has = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.hasOwnProperty);
has({foo:1}, 'foo'); // true
has({foo:1}, 'bar'); // false
```